# Does it make sense to talk about 'position' of a standing wave?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, waves, superposition

In any book that I studied, never saw anything like "position of a wave". Does it have to do anything with quantum particles showing so called "superposition".

Comment: The waves in quantum theory are  **probability**  waves, i.e. The $Ψ^*Ψ$ of the quantum wavefunction gives the Probability of the particle to be found at an (x,y,z,t)

Answer (score 3):

No, it doesn't make sense to talk about the position of a wave. Waves are delocalized. Superpositions of plane waves can have their energy concentrated in a finite region of space, but there will still be a finite extent.